# Два незанятых пространства на жестком диске нужно как-то объединить

Tags: windows, hdd

Столкнулся с вот такой проблемкой:

[image: ...]

Жесткий диск разделен на два незанятых простраства (странно, как так вышло-то) и раздел с важными файлами.

До этого было так:

Диск С - винда,
Диск D
и Диск Н

Решил переустановить систему и удалил раздел с системой и ненужный раздел Н. По идеи должно было образоваться одно незанятое пространство, но нет. Кто скажет как исправить это без удаления раздела D, так как резервные копии делать некуда...

Comment: Расширить раздел с Windows за счет двух незанятых пространств, а уже потом разделить на 2 из под винды, если в этом есть необходимость

Comment: Переместить раздел влево. Правда, перемещение может занять часы (лучше заранее уменьшить раздел, чтобы было побыстрее), и если во время перемещения например вырубится электричество, то раздел останется убитый, так что резервную копию всё равно стоит иметь

Comment: @ZxNuClear насколько я помню, винда позволяет расширять раздел только вправо, но не влево

Comment: @andreymal, возможно вы правы, не исключаю, не помню когда в последний раз вообще была необходимость разбивать диски, учитывая их стоимость

Comment: Я тут поэкспериментировал и выявил, что даже те два пустые пространства невозможно превратить в разделы. После создания раздела ничего не происходит. Похоже нужно искать накопитель для резерной копии...

Comment: Ну а через `gparted live` нельзя подвигать взад-вперёд?